# Crystal Reports: suppress details sections conditional on page number

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Reports question on suppressing different details sections, appreciate any help you could give.

I have 2 details sections, A and B, and I want detailsA to show only on page 1 and detailsB to show only on page 2, but I can't get it to work using conditional suppressing.  For detailsA I suppressed based on the following formula:

if pagenumber = 1 then

formula = false

else

formula = true

end if

And similarly for the detailsB. But when I then go to print this, it only shows page 1 (with detailsA only), it doesn't print a page 2. How do I force page 2 to also print?

(by the way, I'm using Crystal Reports 10, in case that's relevant)

Answer (score 0):

Conditional-suppression formulae:

```
//section a
PageNumber=2

//section b
PageNumber=1
```

** edit **

I suspect the following:

- Suppression formula suppresses page 1.
- Page 2 now is now page 1
- Suppression formula suppresses page 1 (nee 2).

The easiest solution would be to enable 'force new page after' on details A.

Comment: Thanks - though I'm still having the same issue where page 2 simply isn't printing.  It seems like sectionB is properly being suppressed on page 1 like I want, but page 2 just doesn't get created

Comment: What makes it a two page report?  The data or do you force a new page at some point?